# Magnifier Zooming Magento 2

Tags: zoom, magnifier

Hi we been having issues with our Magnifier not having a zoom effect in the product page for Magento 2. For example

https://60c7fa9d26.nxcli.net/71060.html.

You can see the hover effect on the image, but zoom window is not popping up.

We have enabled the Magnifier the view.xml, but it's still not working. Any help will be appreciated

10  
     
     
    300 
    300 
    hover 
    true 
    outside

Comment: Can you provide more details about what is the problem ? From what I can see on the example, there is a zoom window (on the right part of the product page), and clicking on the image displays it fullscreen.